# how to make array dyanamic in android

Tags: android, arrays

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gadl3.png)Person is a structure data model getter and setter
I want to make this dyanamic i.e want to put data from api.
actually i am using this for multiautocompleteselect like gmail so in that when i pass list it throws error that code is setup for this array and i tried to paas list and this array but still null pointer error

```
Person[] people;
people = new Person[]{
new Person("Marshall Weir", "marshall@example.com"),
new Person("Margaret Smith", "margaret@example.com"),
new Person("Max Jordan", "max@example.com"),
new Person("Meg Peterson", "meg@example.com"),
new Person("Amanda Johnson", "amanda@example.com"),
new Person("Terry Anderson", "terry@example.com"),
new Person("Siniša Damianos Pilirani Karoline Slootmaekers",
"siniša_damianos_pilirani_karoline_slootmaekers@example.com")
 };
```

Full code

```
public class TokenActivity extends Activity implements TokenCompleteTextView.TokenListener<Person> {
ContactsCompletionView completionView;
Userfunctions userfunctions;
//    Person[] people;
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<Person> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    userfunctions = new Userfunctions(this);
//        getdata();
//        people = new Person[]{
//                new Person("Marshall Weir", "marshall@example.com"),
//                new Person("Margaret Smith", "margaret@example.com"),
//                new Person("Max Jordan", "max@example.com"),
//                new Person("Meg Peterson", "meg@example.com"),
//                new Person("Amanda Johnson", "amanda@example.com"),
//                new Person("Terry Anderson", "terry@example.com")

//        };

      userfunctions.getCustomerTags(this, "http://acme-crm.cruxservers.in/api/v1/getTags", new Userfunctions.VolleyJSONArrayCallback()    {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JSONArray result) {

            Person ti;
            for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                try {


                    ti = new Person(result.getJSONObject(i).getString("tags"));


                    people.add(ti);


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }


        }
    });

    adapter = new FilteredArrayAdapter<Person>(this, R.layout.person_layout, people) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {

                LayoutInflater l = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = l.inflate(R.layout.person_layout, parent, false);
            }

            Person p = getItem(position);
             ((TextView)       convertView.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(p.getTags());
      //                      ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.email)).setText(p.getEmail());

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean keepObject(Person person, String mask) {
            mask = mask.toLowerCase();
            return person.getTags().toLowerCase().startsWith(mask);
        }
    };

    completionView = (ContactsCompletionView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    completionView.setAdapter(adapter);
    completionView.setTokenListener(this);
    completionView.setTokenClickStyle(TokenCompleteTextView.TokenClickStyle.Select);




              Button removeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.removeButton);
        removeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            List<Person> people = completionView.getObjects();
            if (people.size() > 0) {
                completionView.removeObject(people.get(people.size() - 1));
            }
        }
    });


}

private void updateTokenConfirmation() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Current tokens:\n");
    for (Object token : completionView.getObjects()) {
        sb.append(token.toString());
        sb.append("\n");
    }

    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tokens)).setText(sb);
}


@Override
public void onTokenAdded(Person token) {
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.lastEvent)).setText("Added: " + token);
    updateTokenConfirmation();
}

@Override
public void onTokenRemoved(Person token) {
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.lastEvent)).setText("Removed: " + token);
    updateTokenConfirmation();
}



  }
```

Comment: first you must try yourself it is very much easy

Comment: Thanks for your generous reply it helped a lot ....actually i am using this for multiautocompleteselect like gmail so in that when i pass list it throws error that code is setup for this array and i tried to paas list and this array but still null pointer error

Comment: this question would be invalid if you have had heard of ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

Use List<> or ArrayList<> from collections library

`List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();`

to add
`personList.add(new Person("Marshall Weir", "marshall@example.com"));`

to remove
`personList.remove(0);`

to retrieve
`Person person = personList.get(0);`

Comment: actually i am using this for multiautocompleteselect  like gmail so in that when i pass list it throws error that code is setup for this array and i tried to paas list and this array but still null pointer error

Comment: you can use this for multiautocompleteselect, give it a try

Comment: using arraylist the list gets populate i have done that but when i select the auto complete text its crashes says null pointer expection and when i use the above array which i mention in question which is static  it works but i want to make it dyanamic from api

Comment: can you share your logcat

Comment: @ SaravInfern i have added the code also and above is the logcat link